# Magento 2:How to change default custom module path from app/code to app/customdiretory

Tags: magento2

How to change default custom module path from

> app/code

To

> customdiretory

Answer (score 2):

Go to this file `app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php` file

and add below lines before `foreach` in above file

```
 $pathList[] = dirname(__DIR__) . '/customdiretory/*/*/cli_commands.php';
 $pathList[] = dirname(__DIR__) . '/customdiretory/*/*/registration.php';
```

Comment: @kranthi If this solution is working for you then you can mark as accepted so other user who face same problem can take benefit